# Matplotlib: External legend, spread across multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with 2 subplots, all sharing corresponding graphs, i.e. same label for same color. I want to have one legend over the top of the plots, extending over both subplots. Similar to the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
y1 = x
y2 = 0.1*x**2
y3 = x**3
y4 = x**4
y5 = x**5

fig, grid = plt.subplots(1,2,sharex="col", sharey="row")
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
grid[0].plot(x,y1, label='1')
grid[0].plot(x,y2, label='2')
grid[0].plot(x,y3, label='3')
grid[0].plot(x,y4, label='4')
grid[0].plot(x,y5, label='5')
grid[1].plot(x,y1, label='1')

grid[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=5, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

This example looks almost good. The only problem is that the legend extends from the beginning of the first plot and ends over the middle of the second one. However, I would like the legend to extend over both plots. How can I do that?

Note: Original problem uses 2x3 grid (2 rows, 3 columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle everything from [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132) especially [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132) applies. An easy solution here is to use the figure's subplots parameters to determine the bounding box in figure coordinates of the legend and use the `mode="expand"`.

```
bb = (fig.subplotpars.left, fig.subplotpars.top+0.02, 
      fig.subplotpars.right-fig.subplotpars.left,.1)

grid[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=bb, mode="expand", loc="lower left",
               ncol=5, borderaxespad=0., bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using something like [`figlegend`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html).

```
fig, grid = plt.subplots(1,2,sharex="col", sharey="row")
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
a = grid[0].plot(x,y1)
b = grid[0].plot(x,y2)
c = grid[0].plot(x,y3)
d = grid[0].plot(x,y4)
e = grid[0].plot(x,y5)
f = grid[1].plot(x,y1)

fig.legend((a[0], b[0], c[0], d[0], e[0]), ('label 1', 'label 2', 'label 3', 'label 4', 'label 5'), 'upper center', ncol = 5)
plt.show()
```

The variables `a, b, c, d, e, f` are lists with a single object of type `Line2D`. Alternatively, you can continue to assign labels the way you have done and then just call that property like so

```
fig.legend((a[0], b[0], c[0], d[0], e[0]), (a[0]._label, b[0]._label, c[0]._label, d[0]._label, e[0]._label), 'upper center', ncol = 5)
```